# Ubuntu is not giving the Monkey Patch a VsCode Plugin permissions

Tags: permissions, visual-studio-code

Hello i am facing an error with my vs code i am trying to customize it using a plugin called monkey patch and it shows me this eroor message
NOTE: it was working fine but i did a new installation and now it gives me this eroor

i found the solution if you installed vs code using commanad line you will get this error remove it (uninstall) from the command line and install it manully from a deb file then it will work just fine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cS3Yo.png)

Answer (score 2):

You have to install vs-code from official repositories, and
not snap.

That is beacause When running VScode from a container, monkey-patch can not alter the installation, because it's running from a virtual read-only volume.

So, simply reinstall VSCode via apt / .deb package and you will get it working.

The issue is well discussed [here](https://github.com/iocave/monkey-patch/issues/5)